# One SSID, two routers. How can I force the connection to the correct MAC?

Tags: wireless, router

Basically, the header tells it all. I have two routers configured with the same SSID. The main router is upstairs, and the secondary router is downstairs.

Where I work, normally, the portable sees both routers with about the same strength. But the secondary router is not good for me (too much lost packages, etc.)

Is there a way to assign a name (upstairs/downstairs) to the MAC address of each router?

Comment: Why do you not assign a unique name / ssid to each router? Typically you would do this from the administrative panel.

Comment: Should go to another more corresponding site.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I'm not sure what you mean with admin panel. But from a (very) small business point of view, I want to offer my clients one access point. I don't think other users will be having this problem as their coverage will be clearer.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado, Which other site? I've looked at other Q&A sites, and haven't found 'the' answer. Eric's answer below is also no 100% what I 'need' (and I guess some others as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the network connection (*NetworkManager indicator* -> *Edit connections*, then select your connection and click *Edit*). In the *Wireless* tab there's a textbox named *BSSID*. Type in there the MAC address of the router you want to use and the connection will be locked to it.

[image]

Comment: I understand this works if I would only use my computer in one spot. But sometimes I work downstairs...

Comment: You could create a connection for the second router and manually switch between them as you go up or down stairs.

Comment: Just did that, it seems to work. Cheers!

Comment: OK I know it's been two years, but how exactly do you tell it to switch from one AP to the other, once you've set up the two connections?  Where's the GUI for that?  the network-manager icon just shows me one network, i can't tell which ap it actually is